Passing images from browser input uploads to GoogleAIFileManager
I am building a demo on prompting with Gemini and images uploaded from the browser input utility.
so on the client side - React application, the images are extracted via
Html input:
<input
type="file"
accept="image/*"
onChange={handleImageUpload}    
/>

javascript const file = event.target.files[0]
function that handles file upload
async function googleFileUpload(file) {
    const fileManager = new GoogleAIFileManager(import.meta.env.VITE_GEMINI_KEY);

    // Upload the file and specify a display name.
    const uploadResult = await fileManager.uploadFile(file.name, {
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        displayName: "user Image",
    });

    // View the response.
    console.log(`Uploaded file ${uploadResult.file.displayName} as: ${uploadResult.file.uri}`);

}

The problem is passing an image to the upload file method provided by GoogleAIFileManager. I tried passing the whole file object but that expectedly did not work as it requires a path parameter.
I get the errror
TypeError: (0 , import_fs.readFileSync) is not a function
    at GoogleAIFileManager.uploadFile

Is there a workaround or a solution to this? The common examples i see online use locally stored images that are uploaded to GoogleAIFileManager, which have a clear path as opposed to user initiated browser image uploads.
